# Drill Down treemap from higher level to lower level data?

Tags: tableau-api, treemap

I can create a treemap just fine. I can also create a treemap that shows the main category of info and the sub category of info in the same treemap but that is not what I want.

I thought this could be done with grouping but it does not work out like that.
Is there an action I can write that will perform this task?
Also I need some way to revert back to the top treemap if possible.

Here is an example of what I am getting at the moment.

[image]

What I want to do is start with this treemap:

[image]

Then select a Manager:

[image]

Then I want to display all the Supervisors under that Manager with the Projects under each supervisor. I assume this is either done through some dynamic updating for a sub category or replacing the current treemap with a different one with applied filters but I have had a hard time getting this to work.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well I found a solution thought I don't like it. In order to get the functionality I wanted I had to create a 2nd dashboard that housed the sub category data and then make my first treemap link to the 2nd dashboard.

So I had to write 4 new sheets to build the 2nd dashboard basically mirroring my main dash info and just changing the filter and color sorts to be on the sub category.